# MVC no parameterless constructor but I already have it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constructor

I have a model named 'Credential'. I have already implement parameterless constructor but visual studio still throw exception.
Please help me through this. Thanks

[[image: Error dialog]]

[[image: aaaa]]

Comment: Well that's is not the error is about. If you can fish out the error line or stack trace, That will be very helpful. Just check the controller in which you are using the `Credentials` class, it that has a parameterless constructor? You can look into `output window` to find out about the stack trace.

Comment: I've tried to add parameterless constructor to Controller but it's not working.

Comment: because this is a visual studio's task, there is no stack trace. What could I do now ?

Comment: and what are you trying to do when this error pops up?

Comment: Ohm. sorry, because I could only upload 2 picture. This is what I am doing : https://ibb.co/cMZdRF

Comment: After I click 'Add'. Scafolding appearing in seconds and throws that error :)

Comment: I've found it. The error is about my custom DbContext class doesn't have an constructor due to I use singleton pattern :)

Comment: Certainly your `DbContext` class which using `Credential` model becomes the culprit throwing `MissingMethodException`. Try adding default constructor which using `base` on it.

Comment: Ohm. I've solve it by remove Data Context Class field in 'Add View' form. I wouldn't implement constructor to DbContext class because I use singleton class that means there would no more instance of DbContext class

Comment: not that you asked, but don't use the singleton pattern with a DbContext.  It is designed for unit of work and will only cause you pain.